# How to pass values or objects with link in react-router-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router-dom, react-router-native

```
            <Link
              to={{
                pathname: "/studentDetails",
                state: {
                  selectedStudent: studentsData,
                },
              }}
            >
              {basicData.studentName}
            </Link>
```

**In the above code, it is the example for sending Objects with link in react.js using react-router-dom. And currently I'm developing a react native app and for that, I'm using react-router-native(https://reactrouter.com/native/guides/quick-start) as my router. And how to pass Objects with links using this NPM Package in react native**

Answer (score 0):

can you show what this show you when you try to get the state
cause as I know it should be the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this, im hoping basicData[] is your state array
,<Link to={{
pathname: "/studentDetails",
state: {
selectedStudent: basicData.studentsData,
},
}}
>